# Best practice for grouping/labeling addresses accessibly

Tags: html, accessibility

I'm working on improving an e-commerce site to incorporate better accessibility standards (WCAG 2.0 AA minimum).  I'm trying to determine best practice for handling a listing of addresses that need to be clearly defined.

### The Issue

In checkout I have a list of shipping addresses wrapped with `<address>`.  One will be selected and is identified as such by just a colored outline and checkmark which is only visual so we need a way to clarify that to screen readers.

### Possible Solution?

My solution so far is to set an `aria-label="Selected Address"` and `aria-label="Nonselected Address"`.  This seem to work well in Apple VoiceOver which reads it as a group with the label first making it very clear what it is.  However, with JAWS, it is not reading it as a group nor reading the aria-label.  I can fix that by assigning `role="group"` to each `<address>`.  Since I understand that [`<address>` has no aria role defined by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/address), my assumption is this solution will be fine.  Is that correct or is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: This is not opinion based, there are established patterns on how to make addresses etc. accessible and how to identify selected items to screen readers.

Comment: Agreed. This is a well asked, specific question about accessibility.  What’s with the quick “opinion” closure, thought that was discouraged these days.